# Is it possible to look at the contents of a screen session without attaching to it?

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

Is it possible to peek at the contents of a running screen session?

In order words, look through the window without going in to the room!

e.g.

```
ssh user@remote.server screen --look (and show me what's happening)
```

I suppose a bit like a quick attach and detach in one go while using SSH.

Do you follow me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen -x
```

Attach to a not detached screen session. (Multi display mode).  Screen refuses to attach from within  it‐
            self.  But when cascading multiple screens, loops are not detected; take care.

You could combine it with `-X hardcopy` option

Comment: Alas, this does not work the way I wanted it to. The option -x just seems to reattach to the running screen and stay reattached... which is not what I want. Yes, I know I can just 'ssh -t user@remote.server screen -rd' which is what I normally do. However, what I want is like an all-in-one series of commands where it would attach, show me what's running, then detach all in one go... do you see what I mean? For example, just like the good old 'ssh user@somehost uptime' - except peek at the running screen session and show me what's happening, then detach and log out of ssh in one go! :-)

Comment: Yes I understand but this feature does not exist in screen. How I said, you can combine it with -X hardcopy. ssh user@somehost "screen -x -X hardcopy /tmp/hardcopy.txt; cat /tmp/hardcopy.txt"

Comment: Wow, that works... now I see what you mean! Nice, and many thanks! :-)